# undefined method `update_attribute' for ActiveRecord::Relation when called on record retrieved through inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance

I have a polymorphic association relationship happening, and when I retrieve a record through it, such as:

```
hour = my_model.find( keeper_id ).hours.where( "day = ?", day_index )
```

Then try to call update_attributes on it:

```
hour.update_attribute(:start_time, start_time)
```

I get an error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `update_attribute' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x0000010458c708>):
  activerecord (3.0.0) lib/active_record/relation.rb:373:in `method_missing'
```

I assume it's because I retrieved the record through the relationship. 
How can I get around this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Update attribute works on a single record, not on a collection.
Use `update_all` instead (syntax is a little bit different).

Comment: you could also add a ".first" which turns the collection into a single record